# Which Android Layouts should I use to do something like this?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've been trying to create a layout like this:

[image: image 1]

Now I'm not asking for you to do this but could someone at least tell me what should the scheme be (in other words, how should I stack the layouts)?

e.g:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <ViewFlipper>
        <LinearLayout>
            ....All the stuff within the ViewFlipper area...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button id="@+id/btnPrevious"/>
        <HorizontalScrollView >
            <Button id="@+id/page1"/>
            <Button id="@+id/page2"/>
            <Button id="@+id/page3"/>
            <Button id="@+id/page4"/>
            <Button id="@+id/page5"/>
            <Button id="@+id/page6"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <Button id="@+id/btnNext"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The biggest problem is that I have no clue about how to format the views inside the ViewFlipper to look like the sample image in this link:

[image]

Comment: IF any of these questions helped you, please let us know by accepting one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RelativeLayout is the way to go, but on screens with different resolutions, it might not appear the way you want.  With a RelativeLayout, you can align edges to other views, which looks like what you need/want.

Google put together a good guide for targeting multiple screens.

[Targeting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

The ViewFlipper can be positioned like any other view you have listed here, with one warning, you want to make sure all the views added to the ViewFlipper fit in the space provided.

A good tutorial for using the ViewFlipper can be found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634).

Comment: Different resolutions will be a concern. About the RelativeLayout I have never used it because I find it hard to use but this time I'm going to give it a go. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @user1207197 It may look like steep learning curve, but RelativeLayout is really poowerfull.

Comment: Is there any UI editor that I can use to develop the layout? Something like droidraw but easier/less buggy ...

Comment: @Davidoff I have never used DroidDraw.  The newest version of the Android plugin for Eclipse has a pretty good UI tool.  I find it easier to edit the XML directly.  If you're expecting something as powerful as Interface Builder for iOS/OSX, you're out of luck.